# Inserting Data Using Connector/Python with dictionary key/ values

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I want to fill NULL values of a column in table by iterating key and value of the dictionary.

My table is like below

| item_name | item_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | NULL |
| B | NULL |
| C | NULL |
| D | NULL |

and my dictionary is like below

```
dict = {'A': '%', 'B': 'COUNT', 'C': 'COUN', 'D': 'PSI'}
```

What I'm trying now is

```
value = (value, key)
for key, value in dict.items():
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(item_value) values(%s) where item_name =(%s)", value)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

the output I want is

| item_name | item_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | % |
| B | COUNT |
| C | COUN |
| D | PSI |

Would this code accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to update the row in the table.

Use **UPDATE** query instead of **INSERT** .

You can try this code :

```
for key,value in dict_name.items():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table_name SET item_value = {} where item_name = '{}';".format(value,key))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: I want to replace the null values of item_value column with values of dict, can I do                          [for key,value in dict_name.items():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table_name SET item_value = {} where item_name = '{}';".format(value,key))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()]

Comment: Yes that would work.